# Configure in-band OpenFlow Controller with OVS not in miniet

Tags: qemu, openflow, openvswitch

I'm trying to configure a remote OpenFlow controller over an interface which is also part of the bridge OpenVswitch is managing. I am *not* using mininet; rather, I have a real VM host (supporting a few qemu-kvm VM's) with a real ethernet port. I want the tap interfaces plus the ethernet port to all be in the same bridge and managed by OVS. The OpenFlow controller resides on a different host, reachable only through the physical ethernet port. So far I have set the remote controller for the bridge as well as put the failure mode into "standalone". Unfortunatley the network is simply not coming up after a reboot (NB: before I lost connectivity I did verify that traffic was flowing between the VM host and the OF controller host on port 6633). It seems that, at a minimum, I need to update the OVS database with an "in-band" setting in some table, but I'm not sure how to do this or if this will be sufficient (along with the things I've already done). With mininet, setting this "in-band" configuration appears to be handled by the "topo" command, but (obviously) I can't do it this way. Does anyone have any experience with this kind of an OVS configuration?

Answer (score -1):

Try this : 
    #ovs-vsctl add-br br1

```
#ifconfig br1 10.1.2.11 netmask 255.255.255.0     

#ovs-vsctl set-controller br1 tcp:<controller-IP>:6633     

You will be able to see the ovs connected to controller.
```